# get related model set in template

Tags: django

I've got a a model that is related to the User model

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='actual_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    employee_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

Within my template, i'd like to get all instances of Employee where employee_user matches the current user who is logged in.

```
        {% for employee in request.user.employee_set.all %}

              This is an employee.

        {% endfor %}
```

This doesn't seem to be working. I was wondering if you might know why.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% with request.user.employee_set.all|first as emp %}
  {{emp.attributes}}
{% endwith %}
```

**edit 1 :**

```
    {% for emp in request.user.employee.all %} 

          {{emp.attributes}}

    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks! how do I get all employees instead of just the first?

Comment: since you have the related name set, accesing the attributes by  { content in edit 1 above should work }